# Program to check if N^2 number of elements can be converted to a N*N symmetric matrix?

Tags: algorithm, logic

I was solving some problems on matrices the other day when this question hit me. Is there any way we can check if N^2 number of elements can be arranged in such a way that they form a symmetric matrix?

For instance, if N=3, then N^2=9

Let the elements be : 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3.

The above elements can be arranged to form a symmetric matrix like:-

1 2 3

2 3 1

3 1 2

Similarly, 9 1s can be used to form a matrix as follows:-

1 1 1

1 1 1

1 1 1

But the elements 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9, can in no way be arranged to form a symmetric matrix.
I thought about this question a lot but could not come up with a solution. Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an *N*×*N* symmetric matrix, every entry above the main diagonal has an equal counterpart below the main diagonal. This means that, aside from the *N* elements *on* the main diagonal, all elements come in equal pairs. (Elements *on* the main diagonal can also come in equal pairs, but they're not required to; the matrix's symmetry isn't affected by, for example, whether *a*<sub>22</sub> = *a*<sub>33</sub> or not.)

So, you can simply count how often each distinct value occurs, and see how many of the values occur an odd number of times. If there are *N* or fewer distinct values that occur an odd number of times, then the main diagonal of an *N*×*N* matrix can accommodate the unpaired values, so a symmetric matrix is possible; otherwise, not.

Comment: @Neel: Your question isn't tagged with any specific language, so I literally can't provide "the code". But even if it were . . . if you understand the algorithm that I described, then it should be straightforward for you to code it in whatever language you're most comfortable in; and if you *don't* understand the algorithm that I described, then I think you should ask questions about it, with the goal of understanding it yourself.